Error response from the Facebook API using HTTP POST request image header template create
It looks like you're having trouble with uploading an image while creating a template. The error message indicates that the image file type is not supported.  create webhook image template web api
{
"error": "Failed to upload image: Bad Request - {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2388084,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"File type not supported","error_user_msg":"The type of file is not supported.","fbtrace_id":"AVIBECl3zMY_UjPmZ2_xJGk"}}"
}
webhok header image template create
{
    "name": "sample_template_three",
    "language": "en_US",
    "category": "MARKETING",
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "HEADER",
            "format": "IMAGE",
            "text": "",
            "example": {
                "header_handle": [
                    "4:::ARZYakWPisI6S6S3ecVzVOxKCXEE6DUhPrQ4uLGo_yf0dm0xLwztHIucOUQVj-Y2aaH8lgOGf8S3Gsdxkwlri87RAV_XVUbEF601FcoiZ0demA:e:1726998106:1166948137739761:61565371156239:ARb8pzN-yX7r0cj4iw8"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "BODY",
            "text": "df"
        },
        {
            "type": "FOOTER",
            "text": ""
        }
    ]
}

